# CMakeError: package configuration by moveit_common

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that uses moveit2 and when I try to build it with colcon build I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findmoveit_common.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "moveit_common", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "moveit_common"
  with any of the following names:

    moveit_commonConfig.cmake
    moveit_common-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "moveit_common" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "moveit_common_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "moveit_common" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

I tried to uninstall and install moveit with the command: `sudo apt install ros-foxy-moveit`.  I sourced the ros environment from the directory I'm calling colcon build: `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`. I added `<build_depend>moveit_common</build_depend>` in my package.xml and `find_package(moveit_common REQUIRED)` in my CMakeLists.txt. None of those worked I didn't find anything relevant online so far. I don't understand how I can add the installation prefix of moveit_common in my CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. What is the problem here?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, ROS2 Foxy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392563/cmakeerror:-package-configuration-by-moveit_common/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a long search, I found out that `moveit_common` is not installed together with `moveit`. I installed it separately with:

```
sudo apt install ros-foxy-moveit-common
```

---

Originally posted by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) with karma: 51 on 2021-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-12-20**:
Please report this on the MoveIt 2 issue tracker if you feel that package should be installed by default.